# How to make status "read" to "unread" by using unread gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, read-unread

I can mark a `post` by using `unread` gem.

```
post = Post.first
post.mark_as_read! for: current_user
```

But I couldn't find how to "unread" the post that is marked as "read".
How can I make it?

Comment: just a guess, you can set `read_at` to nil it will mark post as unread

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at the [issues page for the gem on github](https://github.com/ledermann/unread/issues/25) you'll see that this has been brought up there. There doesn't seem to be an official way to do this with the gem; however, user firedev over on github put up his solution.

```
  def mark_as_unread_except current_user
    ReadMark.where(readable_type: self.class.class_name, readable_id: id).each(&:destroy!)
    mark_as_read!(for: current_user)
  end
```

This might be what you need. But take a look at the full page for commentary and ideas. As of now, there is no offical way to do this with the gem.

Answer (score 0):

My working approach is:

```
post.read_mark(current_user).destroy!
```